# PhpStorm Live Template ENUM not showing suggestions

Tags: phpstorm

I have a live template for todos and I would like a dropdown list when I create them that give me the options of "todo", "fixme" and "note". I understand that I can use `enum` for this but I can't seem to get it working properly. Here is a screenshot of my live template:

[image: Live template image]

And here is a GIF of the use of that live template:

[image: Live Template in action]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what I've came up with. You have to surround strings with quote signs there, please see:

[image: gif]

and

[image: setup]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, you must you double quotes and not single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is the correct answer, but this might help someone out.  If you are stuggling to have your enum stick, you have to enter it in like

enum("thing1","thing2","thing3")

**Then hit enter**.  (Clicking out of the table field doesn't keep your options)